# Cant use multiple indexes in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, indexing

i am trying to make second page for my spring but the second one doesnt upload.

[image]

Info from localhost
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Sat Mar 02 22:16:05 MSK 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: Can you share your properties file and controller/About class?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** You need to move your controller folder at the same level as your `@SpringBootApplication` class .

**Explanation:**

Spring boot scan components starting from the folder where your `@SpringBootApplication` class is located, following all sub-folders.

> A single **@SpringBootApplication** annotation can be used to enable
>   those three features, that is: *@EnableAutoConfiguration, @ComponentScan, @Configuration*.
>
> **@ComponetScan** enable *@Component* scan on the package where the
>   application is located.

In your example, you have your main class at `src/java/resume/demo`, but your controllers are at `src/java/`. Therefore controllers are never load. Spring application is able to serve index page because auto configuration, if you debug your code you will see your controller index method is never executed.

Read [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) for best practices coding:

> We generally recommend that you locate your main application class in
>   a root package above other classes. The @SpringBootApplication
>   annotation is often placed on your main class, and it implicitly
>   defines a base “search package” for certain items. For example, if you
>   are writing a JPA application, the package of the
>   @SpringBootApplication annotated class is used to search for @Entity
>   items. Using a root package also allows component scan to apply only
>   on your project.